# turn server appears to be broken

Tags: node.js, webrtc, turn

i know there are not any free turn server available for webrtc , but i read that http://numb.viagenie.ca/ provide free turn server , so i sign up at there account and they gave me username and password.
and i use this username and password just like this

```
{
    "urls":["turn:numb.viagenie.ca"],
    "username": "mygmailid@gmail.com",
    "credential": "password_which_i_provide_at_register_time"

  }
```

i add this turn server in my code but it always gave me error turn server appears to be broken. can any one tell me what wrong in this?

and is anyone know free public turn server because i want it for final year project not production level.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure about free TURN servers

Probably you can try to use some Google TURN servers that they use here for testing https://test.webrtc.org/, I just checked for browser console and found this:

[image]

not sure about lifetime of these servers & credentials, but you can try and let us know

Also you can install your own TURN server https://github.com/coturn/coturn . For example buy a 5$ server on DigitalOcean https://www.digitalocean.com/pricing/ . This is very cheap

Comment: that's google turn server are not working it gives me ice failed.

Comment: installing own turn server not possible for me on my pc because my router is already behind NAT and internet provider use PPPOE connection that won't allow us to forward port(i read this in google).

Comment: you should install it on some public server. I propose you to buy a simple 5$ Digital Ocean server